# Proper way to create array/list of arrays from arrays/lists of elements in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have numpy arrays or lists `a` and `b` with the same lengths, e.g. `a = numpy.array([1,2,3]), b = numpy.array([4,5,6])` and I want to create a numpy.array or list of pairs of the form `numpy.array([a[i],b[i]])`. The following code in principle works:

```
P = [numpy.array([a[i],b[i]]) for i in range(len(a))]
```

However, I suspect that there is a more elegant way to do it. Moreover, the above code does not work in case `a` and `b` are scalars, rather than arrays. Ideally, I would like the code to be able to handle both cases. Any suggestions?

Comment: The "zip" function is a starting point.

Comment: There is no built-in `array`; if you mean Numpy arrays then explicitly say and show that, similarly if you mean the standard library `array` module or anything else.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks! It does not work if a and b are scalars, though, right?

Comment: Cool, added a separate duplicate link for Numpy-specific approaches.

Comment: What's wrong with `np.array((a,b))`?  or its `transpose`?

Comment: @hpaulj That appears to also work, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) arrays:

```
P = list(np.c_[a, b])
```

Or:

```
P = list(np.vstack([a, b]).T)
```

Output:

```
[array([1, 4]), array([2, 5]), array([3, 6])]
```

*NB. It's generally not a good idea to have lists of arrays, better keep the stacked array.*

```
np.c_[a, b]

array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])
```

Reproducible input:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6])
```